# Redux nested state design

Tags: redux

Currently having a state which is getting more complicated an I'm wondering if i'm doing it wrong, see below for an example of a reducer i'm using.

```
case RECEIVE_DEPARTMENT_DAYDATA: 
    return {
        ...state,
        departments: {
            ...state.departments,
            [action.payload.targetDepartment]: {
                ...state.departments[action.payload.targetDepartment],
                dayData: {
                    ...state.departments[action.payload.targetDepartment].dayData,
                    [action.payload.day]: {
                        ...state.departments[action.payload.targetDepartment].dayData[action.payload.day],
                        [action.payload.targetField]: {
                            ...action.payload.data,
                            isFetching: false,
                            receivedAt: new Date(),
                            didInvaldiate: false,
                            didCall: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Is it better to move dayData to it's own reducer or does it make no difference?

Comment: This would need a big refactor in my opinion. There is no way someone will read and understand any of this in a reasonable amount of time. When you end up spreading a huge amount of properties from the original state, it's a good sign that you might also need to change the structure of the data.

Comment: @BalázsÉdes that's what I was thinking. I'm such a rookie to state design so any help is welcome. Basically I have `dayData` per `department`. This `dayData` also has keys.

Comment: Is there any way you could make your data less "nested"? Handle entities in separate collections, and reference them by id's or something? Maybe check out [normalizr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalizr)

Comment: @BalázsÉdes I'm fairly sure that I can seperate the dayData as a seperate reducer. And normalizr seems interesting however not how i should use it :/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice would be to normalize your state into a flat state.

You should take a look to: https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr
And see the video of Dan Abramov on egghead about normalizing redux state: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-normalizing-api-responses-with-normalizr

This egghead lesson was one of the most important things I learned about how to manage redux state and I highly recommend to see it and read more about this matter.

Recently twitter released their mobile website with react and redux and there was a article dissecting their state, which might also be a interesting read: https://medium.com/statuscode/dissecting-twitters-redux-store-d7280b62c6b1#.2e55tu6wb

Comment: Didn't know he had a tutorial series! Will check this out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your example of an immutable nested data update is correct.  However, @Canastro is also correct - this is a good candidate for normalization.

I'd encourage you to read through [Redux FAQ: Organizing State](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-nested-data) and [Structuring Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) in the Redux docs, as well as some of the articles in the [Redux Techniques#Normalization](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-techniques.md#selectors-and-normalization) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).